# How do I establish a connection to an OpenEdge database

Tags: node.js, express, openedge, progress-db

I'm trying to connect to the OpenEdge database so that I can perform queries on it. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to connect to it to make these queries.

So far I've tried making a config file, but I'm unsure how to establish a connection to the server using it:

```
"HMMv10": {
    "dbConfig": {
    "connectionString": "DRIVER={Progress OpenEdge 11.3 Driver}",
    "UID": "SYSPROGRESS",
    "pwd": "***",
    "host": "host.local",
    "port": "18210",
    "db": "hmm10"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm putting up what I found to be the answer just in case anyone else is looking for this. Using a REST API in NodeJS I used npm-odbc and the OpenEdge odbc drivers to connect to the database. Even though the npm-odbc package only mentions Unix it does in fact work on windows.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what that config file goes with or how it works but before trying to setup 3rd party software to connect to an OpenEdge database it is a really good idea to use the provided OE tools to verify that you have a properly configured connection available to connect to.

Progress provides a command line tool called "sqlexp" that you can use to test connections.  The easiest way to access that tool is via a "proenv" command shell.  On Windows just open "proenv" (it is installed with the other Progress commands in the "Progress" program group).  If you have a Linux or UNIX install you run $DLC/bin/proenv.

Then start sqlexp like this (I used my local dbname and port number):

```
proenv> sqlexp -db s2k -H localhost -S 9500 -user sysprogress -password sysprogress

OpenEdge Release 11.7.2 as of Tue Oct 24 18:20:59 EDT 2017
Connecting user "sysprogress" to URL "jdbc:datadirect:openedge://localhost:9500;databaseName=s2k"... (8920)

SQLExplorer>
```

If there are no errors and you get the SQLExplorer> prompt that is sufficient to show that there is a working connection available.

If you would like to go the extra mile and prove that you have been granted permission to fetch data try a simple select statement:

```
SQLExplorer> select count(*) from pub.customer;

            count(*) 
-------------------- 
                1117 

SQLExplorer> quit;

proenv>
```

If this does not work then the local DBA has not configured SQL access, or you have incorrect configuration/credentials and no amount of working with your other tool will fix that.

OpenEdge SQL notes:

If you are not already aware - all OpenEdge data is variable length.  Many SQL tools expect that the width of a field is known use metaschema data to get a default value.  If the local DBA has not been maintaining that data via "dbtool" then you are likely to have errors due to data being wider than expected.

sqlexp expects commands to end with ";".

The "pub" schema is the schema where OpenEdge application tables live.  Table names need to have "pub." pre-pended.

Table and field names that contain "-" will need to be quoted.

Comment: Sorry my question was off a little, but your answer was very helpful! I'm currently making a NodeJS application and I was wondering if there is a client you recommend to use or if I would be better of creating a TCP connection to the server?

Comment: It isn't my area of expertise but this seems promising: https://www.progress.com/tutorials/jdbc/connect-to-any-database-or-saas-applications-using-jdbc-drivers-from-node

Comment: It's also not directly my area of expertise, but I think you'll probably have more joy exposing a REST service on the OE database and using that in your NodeJS.